# using replaceWith to replace an element with a DOMstring or multiple elements in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I can't find examples of vanilla javascript `replaceWith` using **multiple elements/nodes**.

Given HTML with numerous children:

```
<span id="parent"><span>Hardware:</span> <br>
the <span id="oldChild">physical</span> components of a <span>computer</span>.</span>
```

Can I use `replaceWith` to swap any one of the `child` spans, say `#oldChild`, with multiple elements AND text nodes (the commas and spaces following these spans):

```
const newSpans = 
"<span id="newChild1">kickable</span>, 
 <span id="newChild2">throwable</span>, 
 <span id="newChild3">punchable</span>"
```

What is wrong with the syntax of the following? And how can I convert this dynamically generated code (above) into an acceptable argument for `replaceWith`?

```
oldChild.replaceWith( newSpans );
```

Many thanks to [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil), below:

```
const temp = document.createElement("div") 
temp.innerHTML = newSpans
const oldChild = document.getElementById("oldChild")
oldChild.replaceWith(...temp.childNodes)
```

Note: Phil advises wisely it would be preferable to avoid HTML strings (ie it would be preferable to use other data structures like objects and arrays).

Comment: I always try and steer clear of using HTML strings. If you can alter that function of yours to produce a more usable data structure, that would be preferable

Comment: I agree, but strings are one dimensional, kinda like my brain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I use `replaceWith` to swap any one of the child spans with multiple elements AND text nodes

The signature for [Element.replaceWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith) accepts a variable number of `Node` or `DOMString` arguments...

> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> replaceWith(...nodes)
> ```

...so, yes

```js
// helper / utility function
const createSpan = (id, textContent) => Object.assign(document.createElement("span"), { id, textContent })

document.getElementById("oldChild").replaceWith(
  createSpan("newChild1", "kickable"),  // Node
  ", ",                                 // DOMString
  createSpan("newChild2", "throwable"), // Node
  ", ",                                 // DOMString
  createSpan("newChild3", "punchable")  // Node
)
```

```css
#newChild1 { color: green; }
#newChild2 { color: orange; }
#newChild3 { color: red; }
```

```html
<span id="parent"><span>Hardware:</span> <br> the <span id="oldChild">physical</span> components of a <span>computer</span>.</span>
```

---

You could also build up an array of *nodes* to pass to `replaceWith` and use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const newSpans = [
  createSpan("newChild1", "kickable"),
  createSpan("newChild2", "throwable"),
  createSpan("newChild3", "punchable")
]

// Add in separators
const newNodes = newSpans.flatMap(s => [s, ", "]).slice(0, -1)

document.getElementById("oldChild").replaceWith(...newNodes) // spread
```

---

If all you've got is a string containing HTML, you can...

1. Create a temporary element
2. Set the `innerHTML`
3. Pass that element's child nodes to `replaceWith`

```js
let newSpans = 
`<span id="newChild1">kickable</span>, 
<span id="newChild2">throwable</span>, 
<span id="newChild3">punchable</span>`

const tmp = document.createElement("div")
tmp.innerHTML = newSpans

document.getElementById("oldChild").replaceWith(...tmp.childNodes)
```

```css
#newChild1 { color: green; }
#newChild2 { color: orange; }
#newChild3 { color: red; }

/* just showing that #oldChild and the <div> aren't included */
#oldChild, div { background: red; }
```

```html
<span id="parent"><span>Hardware:</span> <br> the <span id="oldChild">physical</span> components of a <span>computer</span>.</span>
```